# Akka Event Bus Tutorial

Tags: scala, akka, event-bus

Are there any good tutorials/explanations on how to use the the event bus in akka?
I've read through the Akka doc but I find it difficult to understand how to use the event bus

Comment: http://www.kotancode.com/2014/02/12/using-the-akka-event-bus/

Comment: not constructive?

Where else could I find answers to questions like this?

Comment: kotancode.com link is broken but last version can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20170505210732/http://www.kotancode.com/2014/02/12/using-the-akka-event-bus/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Not sure if there are or aren't any good tutorials out there, but I can give you a quick example of a possible user case where using the event stream might be helpful.  At a high level though, the event stream is a good mechanism for meeting pub/sub type requirements that your app might have.  Let's say that you have a use case where you update a user's balance in your system.  The balance is accessed often, so you have decided to cache it for better performance.  When a balance is updated, you also want to check and see if the user crosses a threshold with their balance and if so, email them.  You don't want either the cache drop or the balance threshold check to be tied directly into the main balance update call as they might be heavy weight and slow down the user's response.  You could model that particular set of requirements like so:

```
//Message and event classes
case class UpdateAccountBalance(userId:Long, amount:Long)
case class BalanceUpdated(userId:Long)

//Actor that performs account updates
class AccountManager extends Actor{
  val dao = new AccountManagerDao

  def receive = {
    case UpdateAccountBalance(userId, amount) =>
      val res = for(result <- dao.updateBalance(userId, amount)) yield{
        context.system.eventStream.publish(BalanceUpdated(userId))
        result                
      }

      sender ! res
  }
}

//Actor that manages a cache of account balance data
class AccountCacher extends Actor{
  val cache = new AccountCache

  override def preStart = {
    context.system.eventStream.subscribe(context.self, classOf[BalanceUpdated])
  }

  def receive = {
    case BalanceUpdated(userId) =>
      cache.remove(userId)
  }
}

//Actor that checks balance after an update to warn of low balance
class LowBalanceChecker extends Actor{
  val dao = new LowBalanceDao

  override def preStart = {
    context.system.eventStream.subscribe(context.self, classOf[BalanceUpdated])
  }

  def receive = {
    case BalanceUpdated(userId) =>
      for{
        balance <- dao.getBalance(userId)
        theshold <- dao.getBalanceThreshold(userId)
        if (balance < threshold)
      }{
        sendBalanceEmail(userId, balance)
      }
  }
}
```

In this example, the `AccountCacher` and `LowBalanceChecker` actors both subscribe into the `eventStream` by class type for the `BalanceUpdated` event.  If this event is event published to the stream, it will be received by both of these actor instances.  Then, in the `AccountManager`, when the balance update succeeds, it raises a `BalanceUpdated` event for the user.  When this happens, in parallel, that message is delivered to the mailboxes for both the `AccountCacher` and the `LowBalanceChecker` resulting in the balance into being dropped from the cache and the account threshold checked and possibly an email being sent.

Now, you could have just put direct `tell (!)` calls into the `AccountManager` to communicate directly with these other two actors, but one could argue that might be too closely coupling these two "side effects" of a balance update, and that those types of details don't necessarily belong in the `AccountManager`.  If you have a condition that might result in some additional things (checks, updates, etc...) that need to happen purely as side effects (not part of the core business flow itself), then the event stream might be a good way to decouple the event being raised and who might need to react to that event.

Comment: Thanks. Just a few questions:  1) Do you just create an event bus by subscribing to one? How does one go about "destroying" an event bus?  2)Is there a specific actor in charge of an event bus?  3)I notice you didn't declare a classifier, is there a default classifier which is selected then?

Comment: The `ActorSystem` will already have an event bus created for it; no need to create one yourself.  As the `ActorSystem` creates the bus, I would assume that the root guardian is in charge of the bus.  I'm not sure what you mean by question 3; can you explain a little more?

Comment: I just read through the [doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/scala/event-bus.html) again, seems I misunderstood my own question. What I wanted to say is that actors in the example above are subscribed to receive a certain message (BalanceUpdated). How would I go about subscribing an actor to a topic where various messages can be sent

Comment: When you say topic, are you talking about something like JMS or AMQP?

Comment: yes, similar to JMS publish & subscribe model

Comment: This answer is very useful. It's also very different to what I started writing after reading the Akka documentation - so despite this question being closed, I think it was a good question.

Comment: thx for good explanation but I want to ask one thing: isnt sending mail in actor listening on events (LowBalanceChecker) dangerous in case of replays of events? How to avoid that - should we send mail just before publishing event on eventStream?

Comment: @freakman, this was not meant to be a fully baked set of logic from the business logic perspective.  It was just meant to demonstrate how to use the event bus.  If you were sending emails for real, you would more than likely have additional checks to make sure that you don't send the same person the same email more than x times in y interval (probably 1 time in 1 day in this situation).

Answer (score 11):

There is an `EventBus` that exists for every `ActorSystem`.  This `EventBus` is referred to as the [Event Stream](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.1/scala/event-bus.html#Event_Stream) and can be obtained by calling `system.eventStream`.

The ActorSystem uses the Event Stream for a number of things including [logging](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.1/scala/event-bus.html#Default_Handlers), sending [Dead Letters](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.1/scala/event-bus.html#Dead_Letters) and [Cluster Events](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.1/cluster/cluster-usage-scala.html#Subscribe_to_Cluster_Events).

You can also use the Event Stream for your own publish/subscribe requirements.  For example, the event stream can be useful during testing.  Subscribe the [Test Kit](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.1/scala/testing.html)'s `testActor` to the Event Stream for certain events (eg. logging events) and you can `expect` them . This can be especially useful when you would not send a message to another actor when something happens but you still need to expect the event in your test.

Note that the event stream only works within one `ActorSystem`.  If you are using remoting events published on the stream do not cross to remote systems by default (though you could add that support yourself).

You could theoretically create a separate `EventBus` if you didn't want to use the Event Stream.

Better docs for the Event Bus are being worked on for Akka 2.2 so check back again when [this ticket](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/2922-add-examples-to-the-guide-of-event-bus) is complete.